# Create JSON array in php and decode it in android. org.json.JSONException: No value for id

Tags: php, android, json

I use below code to create json array in php

```
$jsonData      = array();
$jsonTempData  = array();
$count=0;
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $jsonTempData['id']=$row['_id'];
        $jsonTempData['title']=$row['title'];

        $jsonData[$count++]=json_encode($jsonTempData);

    }
} 
$link->close();
$outputArr = array();

$outputArr['Android']=$jsonData;

print_r( json_encode($outputArr));
```

and decode in android by below code

```
 jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);
JSONArray array = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
    nm.set_id(array.getJSONObject(i).getInt(DBHelper.ID));

    nm.setTitle(array.getJSONObject(i).getString(DBHelper.TITLE));
}
```

But I get This Exception in android

```
: org.json.JSONException: No value for id
```

What is the problem ? 
How can solve this problem ?

My goal is create 2d array in php and convert it to Array of JSON Object to extract in android.

Comment: The problem is that the key DBHelper.ID is not valid. Check the key in the JSON and the DBHelper.ID Matches.

Comment: May i see the json response from the browser ?

Comment: DBHelper.ID is "id" . it's correct

Comment: http://aiga.ir/webservice/borobala/getnewslist.php

Comment: and what is the key in the json for the id ?

Comment: from the above getnewslist.php file, theres nothing with key 'id'. so the error is expected.

Comment: it is 'id' ..........

Comment: I saw. Why it occured, How to solve it?

Comment: am not familiar with PHP, Google it. learn more about JSON. JSON Parsing, and JSON Encoding in PHP

Comment: @ali - I have given my answer below and you can get back 2 me if you have any doubts

Comment: Just for your trying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to following JSON Parsing Exception for `array`

*JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject*

**The fix:**

Instead of changing the array directly into JSON object I first changed the array item into string then I changed it into JSON object

*In the below code I have changed your code to work :*

```
 jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

 JSONArray array = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){

    String strJSON=array.getString(i);

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strJSON);   

    nm.set_id(jsonObj.getInt(DBHelper.ID));

    nm.setTitle(jsonObj.getString(DBHelper.TITLE));
}
```

Here is the complete sample that I tried Just in case you need it

**php part**(test.php)

```
 <?php
header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');
$jsonData      = array();
$jsonTempData  = array();

$jsonTempData['id']="id1";
$jsonTempData['title']="title1";

$jsonData[0]=json_encode($jsonTempData);

$jsonTempData['id']="id2";
$jsonTempData['title']="title2";

$jsonData[1]=json_encode($jsonTempData);

$outputArr = array();

$outputArr['Android']=$jsonData;

print_r(json_encode($outputArr));

?>
```

Resultant JSON:

> ["{\"id\":\"id1\",\"title\":\"title1\"}","{\"id\":\"id2\",\"title\":\"title2\"}"]

Android part:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet req = new HttpGet("http://localhost/test.php");

HttpResponse response;
try {
     response = httpClient.execute(req);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

                                        String result;
                                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"), 8);
                                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                                        String line = null;
                                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                                        }
                                        result = sb.toString();
                                        Log.d("result:",result.toString());

                                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
                                         JSONArray array = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

                                         for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                                             String strJSONobj=array.getString(i);
                                             JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strJSONobj);                                           
                                             Log.d("result",json.getString("id"));
                                             Log.d("result",json.getString("title"));                                       
                                         }


                                        }
                                } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                } // ClientProtocolException
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are encoding the individual rows and not the output array. Also, you may not need the counter.

Try this:

```
$jsonData      = array();
$jsonTempData  = array();
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $jsonTempData['id']=$row['_id'];
        $jsonTempData['title']=$row['title'];

        $jsonData[]=$jsonTempData;

    }
} 
$link->close();
$outputArr = array();

$outputArr['Android']=json_encode($jsonData);

print_r($outputArr);
```